# Difference between Inductive hypothesis and inductive goal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

For example:

$\forall x: \forall y: \forall z:$ 
 x * (y + z) = (x * y) + (x * z)

by induction on z, letting x and y be arbitrary.

What would be my inductive hypothesis and inductive goal in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of induction over natural numbers is:

> If $P(n)$ is some proposition involving a natural number $n$ and we want to show that $P$ holds for all numbers $n$, we have to :
>
> > show that $P(0)$ holds;
> >
> > show that, for any $k$, if $P(k)$ holds, then so does $P(S(k))$;
> >
> > conclude that $P(n)$ holds for all $n$.

The *goal* is proving $P(n)$ for all $n$, which breaks into two separate subgoals:

- first showing $P(0)$ : the *base* case,
- and then showing $P(k) \to P(S(k))$ : the *induction* step. In proving this step, we have to assume the *induction hypotheses* : $P(k)$, and derive $P(S(k))$.

Comment: so the IH = x * (y + z) = (x * y) + (x * z) and  IG i= x * S(y + z) = (x * y) + (x * Sz)?

Comment: @Varoag : I would say : IG is $\forall x \forall y \forall z [x * (y + z) = (x * y) + (x * z)]$ while IH is $\forall x \forall y [x * (y + z) = (x * y) + (x * z)]$. The induction is on $z$.